# Why is a get request being sent when I click the delete button?

Tags: javascript, jsp

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      var ids = $ {
        requestScope.ids
      };
      for (let i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
        $("#delete-" + ids[i]).click(function() {
          var path = "employees/" + ids[i];
          $("#form").attr("action", path).submit();
        });
      }
    });
</script>

...
        <c:forEach items="${requestScope.employees}" var="employee">
            <tr>
                <td>${employee.id }</td>
                <td>${employee.name }</td>
                <td>${employee.email }</td>
                <!--进行判断:0为男性,1为女性-->
                <td><c:if test="${employee.gender==0}">男</c:if> <c:if
                        test="${employee.gender!=0}">女</c:if></td>
                <td>${employee.department.deptName }</td>
                <td><button id="delete-${employee.id }">DELETE</button></td>
                <td><button>UPDATE</button></td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
</c:if>
<form method="post" id="form">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE" />
</form>
```

When I click the delete button, I want the form to be `post`, and it does, but in `Inspect Element`, I see that a `get` request is also being sent. Why is a `get` request being sent?

[image]

Help me please.

Comment: @Roshana Pitigala   Hey,when you edit the question,please check the edit result,you have make the screenshot not show again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is solved. The error is not the form post, it's the redirect. I wrote:

```
return "redirect:employees";
```

when I should of wrote this instead:

```
return "redirect:/employees";
```